# Why was one of the light switches wired differently from other location?

Tags: electrical, switch, dimmer-switch, multiway-switch

Last night I installed a master dimmer and a companion dimmer in the dining room.  Upon removing the wall plate to one of the two switches, I discovered that a black wire was attached to the black screw of the switch and a second black wire attached to the brass screw, while the red wire was attached to the top screw on the other side of the switch, ie the same side as ground wire.  The wiring to the second switch had the red wire attached to the brass screw while the black wire was attached to other side of switch. Although I was confounded, I went ahead and wired the new master dimmer similar to the original switch.  After both dimmers were installed, the lights failed to work upon turning on the breaker, so I rewired with the red wire to the brass screw and the black wire to the blue screw.
Although both dimmers are now working properly, I was hoping someone could tell me why the original switches were both operable despite weird wiring on one of the switches.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are these multi-way switches?  How many different switches is this light controlled from?  Do you have any switches in your home that you don't know what they do?   Also, on your post-it notes, could you note the color of the screws the wires landed on?  They may not be in the same positions.

Comment: I can’t tell either I don’t see black or gold silver combination used on the brands of 3 ways I use.

Comment: @Harper. There are two switch es that control lights, hence a master dimmer & a companion dimmer were installed.

Comment: Ok, I see it.  It looks lke a 4-way switch, but actually that oddball screw is ground.  It threw me because it had a backstab hole (grounds can't) and that green looked rather low-saturation.  These are 3-ways, and the red and black in the same cable are the travelers.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the box in question please?

Comment: Sorry, the post-it notes in the two photos of switches are addressing the wrong switches!  Basically I'm asking why the original switch worked with the black wire attached to the brass screw but didn't work when I wired up the dimmer switch the same.  The dimmer only worked after I attached the red wire to the brass screw and the black wire to the blue screw! (see dimmer schematic)